# Is p(x)dx equal to dp(x)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm confused with the definition of the expectation operator. 
Assume a random variable $X$ having a probability distribution $p(x)$. Then the expected value of $X$ can be computed as $\int xp(x)dx$.

It is noted in [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) that, given a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, 
P)$ as defined in [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space), the general definition of the expected value is

$\int_{\Omega} X dP = \int_{\Omega} X(w)P(dw) $

where $P$ is the probability measure returning an events probability in $\Sigma$. Is this probability measure the same as the distribution $p(x)$. Additionaly. what does $X(w)$ and $P(dw)$ mean?

Also, the Eq. 1 in http://leon.bottou.org/publications/pdf/online-1998.pdf states that 
$E[f(x)] = \int f(x)p(x) = \int f(x)dp(x)$, is this correct or simply there is a notation error?

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: Thanks, but if p(x)dx = dp(x), then dp(x)/dx = p(x) which is not true, no?

Comment: Apologies, that should be $p'(x)dx$.

Comment: If the measure $P$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure then you can write $P(A) = \int_A f(x) dx$ for some $f$. But not all measures can be written this way. Take $P=\delta_0$, for example. The notation $\int X(\omega) P(d\omega)$ is often written as $\int X(\omega) d P(\omega)$. Think of the $P(d\omega)$ as the probability of an 'infinitesimal' slice :-).

Comment: This is a older notation.  Nowadays, you write $\int_\Omega X(\omega)\, dP(\omega)$, not $\int_\Omega X(\omega)\, P(d\omega)$,

Comment: Thank you! Then to answer my own question,  $P$ is a function measuring the events probability in the outcome space, it is not the probability distribution $p_X (x)$. Then $p(x)dx \neq dp(x)$. What if the image of the random variable $X$ is equal to $\Omega$, i.e. its an identity function? Then it seems $p(x)dx = dp(x)$, correct?

Comment: ........anyone?

Comment: http://leon.bottou.org/publications/pdf/online-1998.pdf has been revised since this question was asked; it no longer has an Eq. 1, and its first equation does not resemble what was written in the question. That may suggest an answer to the question of whether the old equation was correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think when you write $EX = \int_\omega x p(x) dx$, the $p(x)$ is the p.d.f. However, $EX = \int_\omega X dP(X)$. The $P$ is probability measure. So they are different.